# Used Goerli instead of mainnet launchpad

Tags: goerli, staking, keystore, validators, mainnet

i accidentally used the goerli.launchpad webpage instead of mainlaunchpad page to generate keys and stake. it looks like the validator was still created. does it make a difference if the keys were created and deposited using the goerli launchpad page? are the eth lost and if something was done wrong how do i fix it? thank you

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! From the comment you posted, there are some steps you may have forgotten to mention. EthStaker community are very helpful https://ethstaker.cc/support and when you get an answer, feel free to post it here to share with others.

Answer (score 0):

This won't affect your real ETH holdings, and you haven't lost any real ETH. However, the rewards earned on the Goerli testnet won't have any value in the Ethereum Mainnet. However, the Goerli testnet is a separate network used for testing purposes, and the ETH on Goerli has no real-world value.

Comment: so does that mean the staking rewards are going to be earned on the goerli testnet and not the etheruem main testnet? if that's the case how come on beaconcha.in there has been a validator created on the mainnet.